# Is it possible to prevent a webView from refreshing/reloading when we go to another activity and come back to the same activity?

Tags: android, android-webview, refresh, reload

1. Activity A = webView which contains smartchatbot(used for answering simple questions) url.

My question is very simple. All i want to achieve is when i go into Activity A and use the smartchatbot. Once i ask few questions to the smartchatbot, and the smartchatbot gives me a link to go to other page/activity. Once i view the page and return back to Activity A which contains the smartchatbot, i want all the previous questions i asked to the smartchatbot to be there. Not only that, even if i click back button the previously questions have to be there. I have tried the **movetasktoback()** method but when i click back in Activity A, the back button acts like a home button and goes to the main home screen of the phone.

How is it possible to achieve this?

I have tried to save the webView state in Acivity A by overriding the onSaveInstanceState method. However, this onSaveInstanceState method was never called. Im not sure whether this method is the suitable solution for what i want to achieve. Please help me. Thanks in advance

```
    private WebView webView;

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState){
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        webView.saveState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if(savedInstanceState != null){
            webView.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
        }else{
            setupWebViewUI();
        }

    }

               private void setupWebViewUI() {
                    webView.loadUrl("contains the smartchatbotURL");
                    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
                    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                }
            }
```

Comment: How about running a webview client on a Service.

Comment: hi @Sai how we suppose to do that? Sorry...im still new to android studio

Comment: Webview is not supposed to reloaded once created in onCreate() unless : 1. the activity was finished & recreated in your logic when you left it. OR 2. The javascript/frontend code for your chat screen does it.

Comment: @SudarshanVidhate how i suppose to prevent the activity from finishing? Should i implement onPause() and onResume()?

Comment: Once chatbot redirect you to other page & you come back to chatbot, onResume() of chatbot activity is called. Please check if chatbot screen logic reloads page in their onResume(). If thats a case, we need to modify/prevent that logic.

Comment: Out of 2 possible causes I mentioned, activity finish & recreation is less likely possible. So either web frontend code or chatbot activity is doing that.